# Setting cookie value to null created by document.cookie

Tags: cookies

I have created cookie using `document.cookie` in a jsp page.

In my servlet (remember its not a jsp page where I can use java script. Its a servlet), I am retrieving cookie value and after its use, I want to delete them. I dont want to delete the cookies by using expiry time. I want to clear off its values. So, I am doing `cookie.setValue("");`

But, when I check the cookie in my Browser, its still holding the value. Its not clearing off.

1. How to clear off its value?
2. Also, is there a way to clear off the cookie name? I know that there is no cookie.setName() function. So, any other means?

After clearing, basically I dont want a user to see the cookies in the browser.

Regards,

Comment: is there a specific reason why you can't use cookie.setMaxAge(0)?

Comment: In my servlet, I have a link, on click of which I have to show a page. Now this page will be displayed if there is no cookie value set by `document.cookie`  So, I have to clear off the cookie. I guess `cookie.setMaxAge(0)` will not help in this scenario. Also, for security reasons, as soon as this servlet is rendered, I dont want any one to see the cookies from Browser. Please let me know, how can I clear off cookie's value.

Comment: a JSP page is essentially a servlet, so whatever you can do in a JSP page, you can also do in a servlet. if you are able to put javascript code in your JSP page, you can also do that in a servlet. you said you have a link in your JSP page to a servlet, so what is the task of this servlet that you have?

Comment: I have set cookie using document.cookie. I want to clear this cookie in this servlet. This servlet's task is to render a page. The page that gets rendered from this servlet, checks if there are any cookies set by my previous web application. If cookie is not cleared off by this servlet, then instead of rendering the page that I wish to show, it will render some other page. If I dont clear cookie, the pages which gets rendered subsequently will not be the correct ones if cookies are not cleared. I am doing some check in those pages, based on cookie.

Comment: How to clear cookie value set by document.cookie in servlet?

Comment: i have posted my response as an answer so that I can format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete cookie in 2 ways, either in your Servlet (as a server-side code), or if your Servlet renders an HTML document, you may add an page onload event as javascript code.

// Server-side Code

```
@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  // Your task here

  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookieName", "");
  cookie.setMaxAge(0); // To delete the cookie named "cookieName", set MaxAge to 0.
  response.addCookie(cookie); // You need to add this cookie to the response to tell the client (browser) that the cookie named "cookieName" must be deleted on the client (browser)

  // Your task here 

}
```

For the client-side cookie deletion, you may check this http://www.webdevelopmentcentral.net/2007/12/client-side-cookie-handling.html